# Interpret and adjust Kalman Filter velocity prediction

Tags: kalman-filters

This is a copy of question I posted in StackOverflow, now I realize that this is better place to find help.

I use [MATH.NET implementation of Kalman Filter](https://filtering.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Filtering.Kalman/DiscreteKalmanFilter.htm)

My example is similar to the example described [in this very useful manual](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Kalman_filter#/Example_application):

> Consider a truck on frictionless, straight rails. Initially, the truck
> is stationary at position 0, but it is buffeted this way and that by
> random uncontrolled forces. We measure the position of the truck every
> Δt seconds, but these measurements are imprecise; we want to maintain
> a model of the truck's position and velocity.
>
> The position and velocity of the truck are described by the linear state space
>
> [image] where x' is the velocity,
> that is, the derivative of position with respect to time.

Math details can be found by the mentioned link.

Finally, I have this very simple .NET implementation with 2 filter parameters (_measurementCovariance and _plantNoiseVar):

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
//set up filter
var xState = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(2, 1, new[] { x0, v0 });

var measurementCovarianceMatrix = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(2, 2, 
new[] { _measurementCovariance, _measurementCovariance / dt,
       _measurementCovariance / dt, 2 * _measurementCovariance / (dt * dt) });

_dkf = new DiscreteKalmanFilter(xState, measurementCovarianceMatrix); 

_stateTransitionMatrixF = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(2, 2, new[] { 1d, 0d, dt, 1 });
_plantNoiseMatrixG = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(2, 1, new[] { (dt * dt) / 2, dt});
_plantNoiseVarianceQ = (_plantNoiseMatrixG.Transpose() * _plantNoiseMatrixG) * _plantNoiseVar; 
_measurementVarianceMatrixR = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(1, 1, new[] { _measurementCovariance  });
_measurementMatrixH = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(1, 2, new[] { 1d, 0d });


//update function
private void Update(double newPosition, double dt)
{
   var z = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(1, 1, new[] { newPosition });
   _stateTransitionMatrixF[0, 1] = dt;
   _plantNoiseMatrixG[0, 0] = (dt* dt) / 2;
   _plantNoiseMatrixG[1, 0] = dt;
 
   _dkf.Predict(_stateTransitionMatrixF, _plantNoiseMatrixG, _plantNoiseVarianceQ);
   _dkf.Update(z, _measurementMatrixH, _measurementVarianceMatrixR);
}
```

Then I tested this implementation for real data I have:

For each X position I invoked Update function and stored Kalman Velocity prediction via:

```
kalmanPosition = _dkf.State[0, 0];
kalmanVelocity = _dkf.State[1, 0];
kalmanSpeedInstant = (kalmanPosition - _prevPosition) / dt;
_prevPosition = kalmanPosition;
```

Here is a plot with results:

[image]

What I cannot understand, why Kalman speed is so small for my example.
Can anyone please help me with this example.

1. **Do I interpret results correctly?**
2. Is this _dkf.State[1, 0] a speed, or am I wrong with that?
3. Were there any mistakes in my assumptions?
4. **How can I get more accurate speed?**

I used the parameters:

_measurementCovariance = 1.5 and _plantNoiseVar = 3.0.

Data I used:

> `new[] //positions                { -0.05, -0.04, -0.04, -0.03, -0.03, -0.03, -0.03, -0.03, -0.02, -0.01, 0, 0.06, 0.07, 0.03, 0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.1, 0.11, 0.12, 0.12, 0.14, 0.15, 0.15, 0.17, 0.18, 0.2, 0.21, 0.25, 0.28, 0.3, 0.35, 0.44, 0.48, 0.56, 0.6, 0.63, 0.67, 0.71, 0.71, 0.73, 0.75, 0.76, 0.79, 0.81, 0.82, 0.88, 1.13, 1.16, 1.16, 1.15, 1.16, 1.19, 1.2, 1.24, 1.26, 1.29, 1.34, 1.66, 1.52, 1.69, 2.04, 2.05, 2.08, 2.12, 2.16, 2.21, 2.28, 2.33, 2.38, 2.45, 2.5, 2.54, 2.59, 2.65, 2.7, 2.76, 2.93, 3.15, 3.23, 3.28, 3.35, 3.41, 3.48, 3.55, 3.46, 3.52, 3.75,  3.83, 3.92, 3.99, 4.08, 4.15, 4.22, 4.31, 4.54, 4.8, 4.99, 5.08, 5.14, 5.22, 5.44, 5.51, 5.55, 5.63, 5.71, 5.8, 5.88, 5.97, 6.06, 6.16, 6.49, 6.57, 6.65, 6.73, 6.82, 6.9, 7.01, 7.16, 7.25, 7.34, 7.42, 7.52, 7.62, 7.71, 7.81, 7.91, 8.01, 8.32, 8.39, 8.47, 8.68, 8.73, 8.78, 8.86, 8.95, 9.24, 9.21, 9.3, 9.4, 9.49, 9.59, 9.7, 9.79, 9.89,  9.99, 10.27, 10.37, 10.29, 10.38, 10.48, 10.58, 10.69, 10.78, 10.87, 10.98, 11.06, 11.15, 11.24, 11.44, 11.54,  11.63, 11.74, 11.84, 11.94, 12.05, 12.17, 12.28, 12.39, 12.48, 12.6, 12.69, 12.8, 12.92, 13.01, 13.11, 13.21,  13.31, 13.52, 13.62, 13.72, 13.83, 13.94, 14.05, 14.15, 14.47, 14.58, 14.69, 14.8, 14.91, 15.02, 15.12, 15.22,  15.33, 15.42, 15.52, 15.62, 15.72, 15.93, 16.03, 16.14, 16.24, 16.36, 16.47, 16.59, 16.71, 16.83, 16.94, 17.06, 17.17, 17.28, 17.4, 17.5, 17.61, 17.72, 17.82, 17.93, 18.04, 18.15, 18.26, 18.37, 18.49, 18.6, 18.71, 19.11,  19.26, 19.17, 19.29, 19.4, 19.51, 19.68, 19.75, 19.96, 20.05, 20.1, 20.28, 20.35, 20.47, 20.57, 20.84, 20.91,  21.28, 21.41, 21.52, 21.64, 21.74, 21.9, 21.99, 22.78, 22.9, 23, 23.12, 23.24, 23.36, 23.48, 23.61, 23.74, 23.98,  24.1, 24.2, 24.31, 24.42, 24.53, 24.63, 24.75, 24.86, 24.97, 25.09, 25.21, 25.34, 25.45, 25.59, 25.71, 25.82,  25.95, 26.07, 26.18, 26.31, 26.42, 26.54, 26.65, 26.76, 26.88, 27, 27.12, 27.24, 27.37, 27.49, 27.61, 27.74,  27.85, 27.97, 28.08, 28.19, 28.3, 28.41, 28.52, 28.75, 29, 29.12, 29.24, 29.36, 29.49, 29.62, 29.75, 29.88, 30.02, 30.15, 30.26, 30.37, 30.5, 30.71, 30.82, 30.92, 31.02, 31.11, 31.22, 31.33, 31.44, 31.54, 31.63, 31.73,  31.84, 31.97, 32.06, 32.17, 32.26, 32.38, 32.49, 32.61, 32.76, 32.92, 34.05, 34.13, 34.62, 34.69, 34.75, 34.83, 34.92, 35, 35.1, 35.19, 35.29, 35.4, 35.51, 35.6, 35.72, 35.82, 35.93, 36.23, 36.39, 36.54, 39.18,                }`

> `new[] //time { 0, 0.17, 0.2, 0.23, 0.24, 0.25, 0.27, 0.28, 0.31, 0.32, 0.33, 0.35, 0.36, 0.37, 0.39, 0.4, 0.41, 0.43, 0.44, 0.45, 0.47, 0.48, 0.49, 0.51, 0.52, 0.53, 0.55, 0.56, 0.57, 0.59, 0.6, 0.61, 0.63, 0.64, 0.65, 0.67, 0.68, 0.69, 0.71, 0.72, 0.73, 0.75, 0.76, 0.77, 0.79, 0.8, 0.81, 0.83, 0.84, 0.85, 0.87, 0.88, 0.96, 0.97, 0.99, 1, 1.01, 1.03, 1.04, 1.05, 1.07, 1.08, 1.09, 1.11, 1.12, 1.13, 1.23, 1.25, 1.27, 1.28, 1.29, 1.31, 1.32, 1.33, 1.35, 1.36, 1.37, 1.39, 1.4, 1.41, 1.43, 1.44, 1.45, 1.47, 1.48, 1.49, 1.51, 1.52, 1.53, 1.55, 1.56, 1.6, 1.64, 1.65, 1.67,  1.68, 1.69, 1.71, 1.72, 1.73, 1.75, 1.77, 1.81, 1.83, 1.84, 1.85, 1.92, 1.93, 1.95, 1.96, 1.97, 1.99, 2, 2.01,  2.03, 2.04, 2.09, 2.11, 2.12, 2.13, 2.15, 2.16, 2.17, 2.2, 2.21, 2.23, 2.24, 2.25, 2.27, 2.28, 2.29, 2.31, 2.32, 2.36, 2.37, 2.39, 2.4, 2.41, 2.43, 2.44, 2.45, 2.48, 2.49, 2.51, 2.52, 2.53, 2.55, 2.56, 2.57, 2.59, 2.6, 2.61, 2.63, 2.64, 2.65, 2.67, 2.68, 2.69, 2.71, 2.72, 2.73, 2.75, 2.76, 2.77, 2.8, 2.81, 2.83, 2.84, 2.85, 2.87, 2.88, 2.89, 2.91, 2.92, 2.93, 2.95, 2.96, 2.97, 2.99, 3, 3.01, 3.03, 3.04, 3.07, 3.08, 3.09, 3.11, 3.12, 3.13, 3.15,  3.19, 3.2, 3.21, 3.23, 3.24, 3.25, 3.27, 3.28, 3.29, 3.31, 3.32, 3.33, 3.35, 3.37, 3.39, 3.4, 3.41, 3.43, 3.44,  3.45, 3.47, 3.48, 3.49, 3.51, 3.52, 3.53, 3.55, 3.56, 3.57, 3.59, 3.6, 3.61, 3.63, 3.64, 3.65, 3.67, 3.68, 3.69, 3.71, 3.73, 3.75, 3.76, 3.77, 3.79, 3.8, 3.81, 3.83, 3.85, 3.87, 3.88, 3.89, 3.91, 3.92, 3.93, 3.96, 3.97, 4.01,  4.03, 4.04, 4.05, 4.07, 4.08, 4.09, 4.19, 4.2, 4.21, 4.23, 4.24, 4.25, 4.27, 4.28, 4.29, 4.32, 4.33, 4.35, 4.36, 4.37, 4.39, 4.4, 4.41, 4.43, 4.44, 4.45, 4.47, 4.48, 4.49, 4.51, 4.52, 4.53, 4.55, 4.56, 4.57, 4.59, 4.6, 4.61,  4.63, 4.64, 4.65, 4.67, 4.68, 4.69, 4.71, 4.72, 4.73, 4.75, 4.76, 4.77, 4.79, 4.8, 4.81, 4.83, 4.84, 4.87, 4.89, 4.91, 4.92, 4.93, 4.95, 4.96, 4.97, 4.99, 5, 5.01, 5.03, 5.04, 5.05, 5.08, 5.09, 5.11, 5.12, 5.13, 5.15, 5.16,  5.17, 5.19, 5.2, 5.21, 5.23, 5.24, 5.25, 5.27, 5.28, 5.29, 5.31, 5.32, 5.33, 5.35, 5.48, 5.49, 5.57, 5.59, 5.6, 5.61, 5.63, 5.64, 5.65, 5.67, 5.68, 5.69, 5.71, 5.72, 5.73, 5.75, 5.76, 5.79, 5.8, 5.81, 7.23, });`

Comment: Just a tip: You might want to make sure that the model that the Kalman filter is using for its predictions behaves in an expected way, before using it in the Kalman filter. Would a "virtual truck" attain roughly the correct speed if you applied a specific acceleration for some time on it?

Comment: @A_A thanks for the tip. Do you mean that I need to calculate the average speed by taking into account acceleration? Or I need to change the input parameters to get more valid filtering? Sorry for this probably silly questions, but I am quite new in this subject.

Comment: You mention:
> The position and velocity of the truck are described by the linear state space

If you isolate that model, does it behave as expected on its own? Even before it is embedded in the Kalman cycle.

Comment: @A_A I think that model is pretty good for my case. Do you see any artifacts from the plot? Do you think it is because of model problems?

Comment: No, just a tip as I said in my initial comment to make sure that the model the Kalman filter uses in its cycle matches what is predicted. You could use a 3-5 tap median filter to kill those "Raw speed" spikes, that should make the estimate more accurate.